# How to bind an event for all inputs of form?

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I have a form with inputs (with id's). And i need to bind one event to click on any input in this form.

Now, I use this construction:

```
    $("#siteAdress").click(function(){
        $("#reg-login").click();
    });
    $("#phoneNumber").click(function(){
        $("#reg-login").click();
    });
    $("#reg-email").click(function(){
        $("#reg-login").click();
    });
    $("#reg-login").click(function(){
        // DO SOMETHING
    });
```

How to optimize it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to add a class to all the elements you need to bind on, and use it:

```
$(".event-user").click(function() { /* do something */ })
```

If this is not an option, you can use an `id` for your form, and query all its input children:

```
$("#my-form input[type=text]").click(function() { /* do something */ })
```

And if neither is possible, you can always use a comma-separated list of selectors:

```
$("#siteAddress, #phoneNumber, #reg-email, #reg-login")
    .click(function() { /* do something */})
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the types of inputs you have, you could do it broadly or fine grain it. For example, if they're all `input` type elements, just do it broadly:

```
$('input').click(function(){ ... });
```

Otherwise, if you want to do it specifically for text input types, for example, you can do this:

```
$('input[type="text"]').click(function(){ ... });
```

It's all in the selectors! Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$("form input:text").click(function(){
  $("#reg-login").click();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the general > sign. Meaning you can get the form id and then with one line append the click function to all children:

```
$('#formId > input').each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        //SOME CODE - btw you can ge the value with this.value;
    })
});
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
   $('form input').click(function (e) {
            SearchForm();//Call function you want
            return false; 
        });

   $('form input').keypress(function (e) {
            SearchForm();//Call function you want
            return false; 
   });
```